# Proving $|A \cup B|=|A|$

Tags: set-theory

i have to prove the following: If $A$ is infinite and $B$ is finite then: $$|A\cup B|=|A|$$
I've tried to use the fact that there's a bijection from $N$ to $A$, and use it to send objects from$B$ to $A$, and send $A$'s elements to themselves, but what do i do with the elements from $B$ which get sent to $A$, where do they go? Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I feel like this would require AoC.

Comment: @KennyLau Grand Hotel argument?

Comment: Schroeder-Bernstein theorem

Comment: @ParclyTaxel the Grand Hotel assumes countability

Comment: If by N you mean the natural numbers, there may not be a bijection from N to A. Infinite sets can be "larger" than N, in that sense

Comment: The result depends on the axiom of choice: It is consistent with the other axioms of set theory that there are infinite Dedekind finite sets. If $A$ is such a set, and $B$ is finite and non-empty, then $|A\cup B|>|A|$. If you know that $A$ is not only infinite but also countable (as what you wrote suggests) then choice is not needed and the result is true. In general, precisely what you need is that there is an injection from $\mathbb N$ into $A$. Note that without choice this may be false even if $A$ is a set of reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a well-ordering for $A$ and label the elements of $A$ as $a_x$ where $x$ is an ordinal.

Label the elements of $B$ as $b_k$ where $k$ is a natural number, and let $n$ be the number of elements of $B$.

Define a bijection $A\cup B \to A$ as follows:
$$f(v) = \begin{cases}
a_{x+n}& v = a_x \land x < \omega \\
a_x    & v = a_x \land x \ge \omega \\
a_k    & v = b_k \\
\end{cases}$$

The proof that $f$ is a bijection is left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: No need to invoke AoC or the well-ordering principle. You can pick a well-ordering for an infinite subset of $A$ (such as the image of an injection of $\Bbb N$ into $A$, which we know exists), and do the construction there, not touching the rest of $A$.

Comment: How do you know it exists?

Comment: Because we're told that $A$ is infinite, and by definition of $|\Bbb N|\leq |A|$ there is an injection.

Comment: @Arthur Is the result that "cardinality is a total relation" not based on AoC?

Comment: I have not said that it is a total relation. It could be partial one for all I care. However, how would you define "infinite" if not by whether you can inject $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @Arthur The definition I know is that a set is infinite if it bijects with a proper subset of itself.

Comment: Oh, right, that could also be a definition. However, in that case, you can work with the complement of said proper subset, putting $B$ in there. If there isn't room for all of $B$, you can apply the bijection again and again until you have room for all of $B$.

Comment: @KennyLau I think we can just use countable choice here.  Since $A$ is infinite, $A$ is not empty.  Choose $a_1 \in A$.  Since $A$ is infinite, $A \setminus \{a_1\}$ is not empty.  Choose $a_2 \in A \setminus \{a_1\}$.  Keep doing this until you have an injection $\mathbb{N} \to A$

Comment: @KennyLau I don't know what an ordinal is so i can't well-order A.

Comment: @Arthur I see. I think you should post another answer.

Comment: Alright i got it, thanks arthur and kenny

Comment: @anonymous: That would be dependent choice, which is strictly stronger than countable choice. Although countable choice is indeed enough to prove the existence of an injection from $\Bbb N$ into an infinite set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's clear that there's an injection $A \to A \cup B$.  Assume that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and that $B = \{1, \dots , n\}$.

since $A$ is infinite, find a subset $A' \subset A$ with $A' \equiv A$.  Let $B'$ be the complement of $A'$ in $A$.  Since $B'$ is not empty, it contains at least one element, say $b_1$.  Since $A'$ is infinite, we can repeat the above construction (at most $|B|$ times) to find a subset $A^* \subset A$ such that $A^* \equiv A$ and elements $b_1, \dots , b_{|B|} \notin A^*$

Let $\phi:A \to A^*$ be the assumed bijection.  Define $\Phi: A \cup B \to A$ by $\Phi(a) = \phi(a)$ for $a \in A$ and $\Phi(j) = b_j$ for $j = 1, \dots , n$.  This is an injection from $A \cup B \to A$.

By CBS, there's a bijection.